# Passing Variables to a second page using PHP

Tags: php

I'm sorry to repeat this question, but the thing is that I have done everything and nothing works. My problem is that I'm trying to pass variables to a second page and it won't work.

Page 1:

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="editempresas3.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>&descr=<?php echo $descr;?>&dir=<?php echo $dir;?>&pais=<?php echo $pais;?>&tel=<?php echo $tel;?>&fax=<?php echo $fax;?>&email=<?php echo $email;?>&url=<?php echo $url;?>">

<?php 
$name = $_POST['empname'];
.....etc
          ?>

<input name="empname" type="text" required id="empname" form="form1">
.....etc
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" form="form1" value="Crear">
```

Page 2:

The link will come without the variables
http://www.sample.org/editempresas3.php?name=&descr=&dir=&pais=&tel=&fax=&email=&url=

Comment: You are building your form action as some sort of manual GET. Just link to the php file `action="editempresas3.php"`. Then in the second page do a `var_dump($_POST)` and all your form fields should be available.

Comment: Are you submitting this form to itself? Where do those `$name`, `$email`, etc come from?

Comment: javad, i wrote etc to not bulk up the page, just figure their are their. Ill try the var_dump($_POST), Changing the method="post" to method="get" already solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use `GET` method to achieve this.

change

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="editempresas3.php">
```

to

```
<form method="GET" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="editempresas3.php">
```

P.S: if you're form is not uploading anything you can't even miss `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: This won't work, the action is wrong, the get needs to be built on submit. PHP cannot populate variables without processing them through REST.

Comment: I see you changed it but surely sending a form by GET is not best practice. Sets you up for all kinds of trouble.

Comment: Yes I agree, but he's looking for this solution since he said he wants to achieve an URL like `page.php?foo=foo&bar=bar`

Comment: I know but they've now walked away not understanding the difference or the reason why GET shouldn't be used for forms. What if he has a text area that accepts more than 2000 chars or even less!

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities, from most to least desirable:

1. Use sessions:

   Page 1

   ```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['var_for_other_page'] = 'foo';
   ```

   Page 2

   ```
   session_start();
   $myvar = $_SESSION['var_for_other_page']
   ```
2. Use hidden fields:

   ```
   <form action="secondpage.php" method="post>
     <input type="hidden" name="var_for_other_page" value="foo" />
   </form>
   ```
3. Put the get vars into the action URL:

   ```
   <form action="secondpage.php?var_for_other_page=foo" method="post>
     <input ... />
   </form>
   ```

   In this case you will have variables in both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

**Do *not* use either 2 or 3 to pass sensitive information.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data from a form to a new page, firstly I think your should always use POST. The reason it is not working is you are attempting to send form data via POST but in your action you are trying to build a GET using PHP variables echoed in the there.

e.g.
`action="editempresas3.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>&descr=<?php echo $descr;?>&dir=<?php echo $dir;?>&pais=<?php echo $pais;?>&tel=<?php echo $tel;?>&fax=<?php echo $fax;?>&email=<?php echo $email;?>&url=<?php echo $url;?>"`

This can't work because PHP needs to process it before the HTML is rendered to print the variables you have chosen.

If you change your action to

`action="editempresas3.php"`

You will be successfully sent to the next page and if you then use

`var_dump($_POST);`

On your next page `editempresas3.php` you will get an output of all fields completed in the page 1 form.