# Sending variables to a second page plus uploading image using PHP

Tags: php

Im trying to send variables from page1.php to page2.php and also upload a picture. My codes are huge, so ill try to simplify it at most.

page1.php code:

```
<?php 
$name = $_POST['empname'];
$descr = $_POST['descr'];
//...etc WONT BE WRITING OTHERS VARIABLES.
?>
<form method="GET" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page2.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>&descr=<?php echo $descr;?>">
<input name="empname" type="text" id="empname" form="form1">
//...etc
<input name="file" type="file" id="file" form="form1" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/x-ms-bmp, image/x-png">
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" form="form1" value="Crear">
</form>
```

page2.php code:

```
<?php 
$name = $_GET['name'];
$descr = $_GET['descr'];
$success = "INSERT INTO empresas(name,descr) VALUES ('$name','$descr')";
$data = mysql_query ($success)or die(mysql_error());
if($data) { echo 'It worked'; } else { echo 'wont work'; } ?>
<?php
// ALL the data of uploading a picture from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"fotoemp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);?>
```

Problem: I was trying to make the php string like: www.sample.com/page2.php?name=value&descr=value; so i couldn't because i had the Form method as POST. Good, i change it to GET, and worked perfectly. Now that the string works, i use it, but it wont retrieve the variables. And will the Upload file script will stop working.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var_dump()` is a debugging function. If you want to access an index of the `superglobal array` that is `POST`, simply reference it like:

```
$_POST['empname']; // or 'empdesc'
```

Or loop through it with a foreach loop, but if this is a form submission that's not really needed.

Comment: how can i hide the: array(9) { ["empname"]=> string(8) "PROBANDO"  ... info?

Comment: You can't, that's what `var_dump` outputs. If you want less info, use `print_r` or loop through it and make a custom output function.

Comment: check this link, so u can see what im trying to do. Some1 suggested me to use var_dump for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528129/passing-variables-to-a-second-page-using-php

Comment: They assumed too much of you. `var_dump` is not for what you want. It simply dumps out the entire variable value, no customization. It's for debugging.

Comment: arg, now i receive less reputation because of them, if i delete the question i win my rep pts back?

Comment: You can't delete this question because it has answers. Just learn from this and you'll be fine! :)

Comment: Thanks RUJordan, ill have to make another question, in order to solve this out. Ill make a new one. thx.

Comment: NOOOOO DONT DO THAT. That one will probably be downvoted worse unless it's a completely new question. Just edit your old one

Comment: RUjordan, if u r online, please check my post.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from post use this:

```
$_POST['fieldName']
```

where `fieldName` is name of input in your html form code:

```
<input type='text' name='fieldName' />
```

Answer (score 0):

var_dump es una función para depurar, me refiero que es para buscar errores o cosas que no van bien. Si quieres acceder a los datos, usa `$_POST['empname']` o el valor que envíes a través del formulario en el atributo name="". Feliz coding! ;)

-- en (i used spanish because I realized that he speaks spanish --

var_dump is a debugging function, a mean it's to search for bugs or things that aren't ok. If you wanna access to data, use `$_POST['empname']` or the value that you sent through the form in the attribute name="". Happy coding. :)

Comment: Could you translate this to english please?

Comment: Done. I wrote it in spanish because I realized he speaks spanish. :P